# Why EXECUTABLE_OUTPUT_PATH does not work?

Tags: c++, build, cmake

I have such files

```
.
├── CMakeLists.txt
└── src
    ├── CMakeLists.txt
    └── main.c
```

And this is the content about this files

```
$ cat CMakeLists.txt
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5)
PROJECT (HELLO)
ADD_SUBDIRECTORY(src bin)
SET(EXECUTABLE_OUTPUT_PATH ${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/binarydir)

$ cat src/CMakeLists.txt
ADD_EXECUTABLE(hello main.c)

$ cat src/main.c
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    printf("Hello World from t1 main().\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Then I build it with following command

```
$ mkdir build
$ cd build
$ cmake ..
$ make
```

This is the result directory structure

[image]

Then the binary `hello` will produced in directory `build/bin` as the picture, but it should be in `build/binarydir` since I have `set` the value for `EXECUTABLE_OUTPUT_PATH`, isn't it? What I have missed?

Comment: Variable [EXECUTABLE_OUTPUT_PATH](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.9/variable/EXECUTABLE_OUTPUT_PATH.html) is an old way. New code should prefer [CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.9/variable/CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY.html).

Comment: @Tsyvarev You mean `SET(CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/binarydir)` works for you?

Comment: No, setting the variable still has to precede `add_subdirectory` call. But instead of `EXECUTABLE_OUTPUT_PATH` variable it is better to set `CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY` one.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are creating executable target before setting `EXECUTABLE_OUTPUT_PATH`. Move `SET(EXECUTABLE_OUTPUT_PATH ${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/binarydir)` line before `ADD_SUBDIRECTORY(src bin)`.